# Using random values in Selenium

Tags: selenium, testing

Is it possible to instruct Selenium to use a randomly generated value (name) for further testing?

I have only just started using Selenium and have very little knowledge on the program. I have created a script that generates a random name, I want to be able to take this name and include it in another test

hope this makes sense! appreciate anyone's input

Comment: This question is way to broad. How to use the generated name? when? for what purpose? you need to explain *exactly* what is the problem.

Comment: ok thanks - so i'm creating test cases in Selenium to run automated tests for a program we support. For example, I need to create a referral. I have created a java script file that generates a random name for said referral. My problem is that I need to know how to get Selenium to take this randomly generated referral and include it for further testing

Comment: You didn't add any relevant data. Please go over [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: I shall try my best Guy, thank you for responding. I'm having trouble knowing what terms to use as i'm not tech savvy

Answer (score -1):

Capture the random name to a string and make it static. Use in other tests by calling it.

Can you please post some code where exactly you stuck? Are you using Selenium Webdriver?